# Able to do Buy subscription in India but not able to do in Norway on the same app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

I implemented In App purchase in ios app.I am using it for testing now, using Sandbox mode. I am able to purchase app in India. But In Norway I am not able to purchase app. It is not showing any progress.